# SwiftUI, Notification about the end, the cancellation of a drag operation

Tags: swiftui, drag-and-drop

I have implemented drag and drop for one view. Now I want to change the state of the source view at the start of a drag operation and change the state back at completion or cancellation.
The following example code should illustrate this.

```swift
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct DragableView: View {
    @State var isActiveDropTarget: Bool = false
    @State var isDragged: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello world")
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                        .fill(Color.accentColor.opacity(0.1))
                        .opacity(isActiveDropTarget ? 1.0 : 0.0))
            .opacity(isDragged ? 0.5 : 1)
        .onDrag {
            isDragged = true
            return NSItemProvider(object: "Test" as NSString)
        }
        .onDrop(of: [UTType.data], delegate: self)
    }
}

extension DragableView: DropDelegate
{
    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo)
    {
        isActiveDropTarget = true
    }
    
    func dropExited(info: DropInfo)
    {
        isActiveDropTarget = false
    }

    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool
    {
        isActiveDropTarget = false
        /* Handle drop
         ...
         */
        return true
    }
}
```

The problem with the current implementation is that I do notice when a drag operation starts (`.onDrag` is called), but I don't know when the operation ends.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to solve this? I'm stuck on this too.

Comment: @FrontFacingWindowCleaner: No, I gave up on that. I'm afraid we don't see any improvement before the next iOS major release.

Comment: I actually came up with something. I placed an .ondrop on the entire view, and created a new dropdelegate just for this case. All the delegate does is set a 'dragging' boolean back to false. Then in all the other delegates I also set this boolean to false when a drop is performed. This works as a 'drag ended' indicator.

Comment: That is a brilliantly creative workaround :) Thanks so much!

Comment: You should put it down as an answer really as it’s worthy of a green tick.

Comment: Unfortunately this trick doesn’t seem to help with my other issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72016643/ability-to-be-informed-when-ondrag-ends-without-any-movement-i-e-immediatel. If you have any other smart ideas like above, would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit late, but I'm sharing my solution because there is no recent answer.  It uses a concept similar to that proposed by @FrontFacingWindowCleaner, but does not use Delegates.

### Key concepts to implement isDragActive

- This project uses SwiftUI's' `Transferrable` drag and drop View modifiers `.draggable()` and `.dropDestination()`
- It declares an `isDragActive` `@State` var to hold the current dragging state
- It also declares an `isDragActive` environment varable to inject the current dragging state into all child Views
- It uses the `isTargeted:` closure with all of the drop target `.dropDestination()` view modifiers to track dragging status for all expected drop targets
- It also implements a `.dropDestination()` view modifier on an outer View in order to continue tracking the drag when none of the expected drop targets is being targeted

#### Tips

- Use `.onChange(of: isDragActive)` to trigger desired actions when dragging begins or ends anywhere within the outer View.
- This project uses it to change the `FocusState` of the `List` view so the background color of a selection will change during a drag.

A complete buildable demo project is at: https://github.com/Whiffer/SwiftUI_isDragActive

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = Set<Node>()
    @FocusState private var isListFocused: Bool
    @State private var isDragActive = false  // <<<<
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(nodes, id: \.self , children: \.children, selection: self.$selection) { node in
                NodeView(node: node)
            }
            .focused($isListFocused)
            Text("isDragActive: \(isDragActive.description)")
        }
        .dropDestination(for: Node.self) { _, _ in
            return false
        } isTargeted: { isDragActive = $0 }   // <<<<
        .onChange(of: isDragActive) { _, newValue in
            if newValue == true {
                print("Drag started")
                isListFocused = false
            }
            if newValue == false {
                print("Drag ended")
                isListFocused = true
            }
        }
        .environment(\.isDragActive, $isDragActive)  // <<<<
    }
}

struct NodeView: View {
    var node: Node
    @State private var isTargeted = false
    @Environment(\.isDragActive) private var isDragActive  // <<<<
    var body: some View {
        Text(node.name)
            .listRowBackground(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .circular)
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                .foregroundColor(isTargeted ? Color(nsColor: .selectedContentBackgroundColor) : Color.clear)
            )
            .draggable(node)
            .dropDestination(for: Node.self) { droppedNodes, _ in
                for droppedNode in droppedNodes {
                    print("\(droppedNode.name) dropped on: \(node.name)")
                }
                return true
            } isTargeted: {
                isTargeted = $0
                isDragActive.wrappedValue = $0  // <<<<
            }
    }
}

struct DragActive: EnvironmentKey {  // <<<<
    static var defaultValue: Binding<Bool> = .constant(false)
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var isDragActive: Binding<Bool> {  // <<<<
        get { self[DragActive.self] }
        set { self[DragActive.self] = newValue }
    }
}

let nodes: [Node] = [
    .init(name: "Clothing", children: [
        .init(name: "Hoodies"), .init(name: "Jackets"), .init(name: "Joggers"), .init(name: "Jumpers"),
        .init(name: "Jeans", children: [.init(name: "Regular", children: [.init(name: "Size 34"), .init(name: "Size 32"), ] ), .init(name: "Slim") ] ), ] ),
    .init(name: "Shoes", children: [.init(name: "Boots"), .init(name: "Sandals"), .init(name: "Trainers"), ] ),
    .init(name: "Socks", children: [.init(name: "Crew"), .init(name: "Dress"), .init(name: "Athletic"), ] ),
]

struct Node: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var children: [Node]? = nil
}

extension Node: Transferable {
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        CodableRepresentation(contentType: .node)
    }
}

extension UTType {
    // Add a "public.data" Exported Type Identifier for this on the Info tab for the Target's Settings
    static var node: UTType { UTType(exportedAs: "com.experiment.node") }
}
```